# ngroute support for multiple url parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a major gap in operating ng routing functionalists.
Here is what I want to achieve: I have a main page which directs to dashboard.html and another 
buildings.html. 
The buildings page could be called with many parameters, such as: id, type, color
So a traditional url would look like that:

```
/buildings?id=110&type=special&color=red
```

So as far as I understand in angular ngroute I should have this structure:

```
$routeProvider

            // route for the main page which will direct to the buildings page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'web/pages/dashboard.html',
                controller  : 'dashboardController',
                controllerAs : 'dashboard'
            })

            // route for the main page which will direct to the buildings page
            .when('/buildings/:buildingId/:buildingType/:buildingColor', {
                templateUrl : 'web/pages/buildings.html',
                controller  : 'mainController',
                controllerAs : 'buildings'
            })
            ;

});
```

And the url should be like:

```
/buildings/110/special/red
```

What I don't get is how to call for the buildings page with only id or with type and color?
And if I have 7 parameters and want to trigger a call with only 3, how should I do that?

I'm using $location.path to shift between pages when needed based on gui events, for example:
$location.path( '/buildings/'+$scope.id);

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options here:

- Either you'll orther your parameters so that when you want to use param 5, you're sure, that previous params must also be defined
- Or you can just use some character that represents null, like -, or something. Your URL would look like `/buildings/5/-/red`
- Or (the best option) you *should* leave obligatory parameters in URL (like IDs) and put optional parameters in URL get parameters (like you showed in oldschool style parameters). Then your URL would look like this: `/buildings/5?color=red`. You can access those parameters from AngularJS using `$location.search().color` etc.

Comment: I tried the third approach but wasn't able to generate a url string using location.path, for example $location.path( '/buildings/'+$scope.multiElement.id) generated : /building%3FId=110. seems like the ? is encoded

Comment: Again there are two ways here:
a) `$location.url('/buildings/5?color=red&type=special');`
b) `$location.search('color', 'red').search('type', 'special').path('/buildings/5');`

Comment: Yeah, but if I'm going for the third approach, how can I generate a traditional url using angular? also some say this is not recommended as it makes the page reloads

Comment: What do you mean by traditional URL string? Using $location service with relative URLs never makes the page reload in Angular.